# RegExpr to insert space before \n

Tags: php, regex

I'm need to insert space before new-line-symbol if it's not yet. For ex, in the text like this:

```
Some text 
need space dfgfgfkgkf
```

insert space between 'text' and 'need'..

```
$pattern = "/[^\s]\n/i";
$replace = " \n";
```

but this regexp don't work

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your newline character is `\n`? I would go for a more general solution and use

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\S)(?=\r?\n)/',' ', $str);
```

I use a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead assertion to find the position at the end of the row, therefor only a space as replacement is needed.

Comment: +1 for the only answer so far that handles the "not already preceded by a space" requirement **and** allows for newlines other than `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$pattern = "/\n/";
$replace = " \n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code below and it worked:

```
$str = "line1\nline2";

echo preg_replace('/\n/',' \n', $str);
```